# Data loss between Axios/Express

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I've encountered a weird bug in my program, specifically when I make a call in axios to delete an user.

Axios call:

```
export const deleteUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
    console.log(userData);
    axios
        .delete('http://localhost:5000/api/users/delete', userData, { crossdomain: true })
        .then(res => history.push("/login")) // redirect to login on successful removal
        .catch(err =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        );
};
```

console prints out userData as expected (I only need the id to delete the user).

```
{
  "id": "5e3143dcf5b0337d90b8df74",
  "name": "",
  "email": "",
  "password": "",
  "password2": ""
}
```

However when I process the call with data I just received on the server side:

```
router.delete("/delete", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body.id }, {new: true}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
        console.log(doc);
        res.status(200).json(doc);
    });

});
```

it prints out:

```
{}
```

Comment: please, can you post the results of `console.log(userData)`?

Comment: I ask because, according to this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897, the "body" part should be passed as `config.data` for instance: `axios.delete(url, { data: { foo: "bar" } });`

Comment: Please don't copy all your source code, just make a minimal example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @GrafiCode Yeah, thats it, thanks mate. It works like that with my other calls tho which i find surprising. I can post my whole redux action file if you'd be interested.

Comment: If you'd like to make an answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: @nfsu you can self-answer your question, and then later accept it ;)